# How to make fixed sidebar stop at footer [JQUERY]?

Tags: jquery

It has been asked a million times, I know. However, none of the solutions on Google seem to work.

My code works great! Until it hits the footer. It seems to detect it has hit the footer; but then if I scroll any further it returns to being position fixed. I have used console.log to determine it seems the if statements are conflicting...

Any help would be appreciated!

```
// When the user scrolls...
$(window).scroll(function() {

var offset = $('#offset').offset(); // trigger point for sidebar to become fixed... sits at top of page
var footerTop = $('#footer').offset();
var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
var sideBarBottom = sidebar.offset().top + sidebar.height();

// Make it sticky
if (!(sideBarBottom > footerTop.top - 25)) {
    console.log("SBB" + sideBarBottom + "   FT: " + (footerTop.top - 25));
    if (windowTop > offset.top) {
        sidebar.css('position', 'fixed');
        sidebar.css('top', '80px');
        sidebar.css('left', '69.5%');
        sidebar.css('width', '270px');
    } else {
        sidebar.css('position','static');
        sidebar.css('width', '270px');
    }
} else {
    console.log('absolute');
    sidebar.css('position', 'absolute');
    sidebar.css('top', $(window).height() - ($('#footer').height() + 100));
    sidebar.css('width', '270px');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's happening without seeing the HTML context, but it seems like you're saying that as soon as the code under `console.log('absolute')` runs, your collision test stops working correctly on subsequent tries.

If nothing else, the statement `sidebar.css('top', $(window).height() - ($('#footer').height() + 100)))` looks wrong.  You're calculating the sidebar's position from values that have nothing to do with the footer's position, so it's hard to see how that would cause it to show up in the right place on the screen; I'd have thought you wanted something more like `sidebar.css('top', (footerTop - sidebar.height() - 25) + 'px')`.  (Assuming the sidebar's layout parent is the document)

Comment: I made a new post that explained things a bit better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684277/jquery-fixed-sidebar-strange-bug